# How to download a specific part of a .m4s file

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, video-encoding, mpeg-dash

I need to download only a specific part (timestamp a to timestamp b) of an m4s file or actually 2 because audio and video tracks are on separate files, I have tried linearly mapping timeline to the file size but it seems like it is not the right approach since the two don't seem to match, and sometimes the audio length doesn't even match the video.

Is there any way to know where to start cutting the file given the timestamps without downloading the whole file first?

EDIT: reply
I need to make a tool to download a specific part of a video from a streaming website (the streaming service is aware and agrees as long as we don't share the tool with anyone). We've only managed to find a single m4s file source and it contains the whole video, and when I click on a certain part of the player timeline an http request is sent with a range in bytes, the problem is to know how to map the time to the byte range, is this information somewhere in the header and if so how would I read it？

[image: request header]

Answer (score 0):

An m4s file is actually already a segment of the video, and the segments are usually, but not always, a given size - for example 2, 5 or 10 seconds long.

Once your client has read the header of the file, which will be at the start for a DASH stream, you should be able to download whatever segments you want.

Note that there are several different manifest (index file) formats for DASH files - the segments may simply be named sequentially so you can work out the time you need based on the segment size, or the manifest may use a segment timeline approach where the segments are relative to a given start time.

It's worth remembering also that for a live stream you are clearly limited to segments which are available at that time, and there may be a limit to how long older segments are kept available for streaming, i.e. a live 'window'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But my case is a bit different, I need to make a tool to download a specific part of a video from a streaming website (the streaming service is aware and agrees as long as we don't share the tool with anyone). We've  only managed to find a single m4s file source and it contains the whole video, and when I click on a certain part of the player timeline an http request is sent with a range in bytes, the problem is to know how to map the time to the byte range, is this information somewhere in the header and if so how would I read it？